# ajax datatable won't call php file,tried multiple solutions none work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my function to call the php file to populate the datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" > 
    $(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_data();

 function fetch_data()
 {
  var dataTable = $('#my-example').DataTable({
   "processing" : true,
   "serverSide" : true,
   "order" : [],
   "ajax" : {
    url:"fetch.php",
    type:"POST"
   }
```

> > i've checked the source of the page on chrome the javascript is executed but not the php, any help would be great.

Comment: Your code is invalid. Could you post the same code as you tested?

Comment: Correct example, please

Comment: maybe you should do it without var dataTable = .. I can find that no where in the docs its always just $('#myTable').DataTable( {ajax: '/api/myData'} );

Comment: i've tried that at first and then changed it to that and it still doesnt seem to make a difference @ChristopherSupertramp

Comment: have you also tried it without the function at all? If you just want to load it at the beginning you will not need that function..

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp just tested it without function same result

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is the code as i tested, i am not proficient in javascript.

Comment: Using DataTable's AJAX function is not simple if you don't know Javascript very well. I would get rid of the `fetch_data()` function and put what you've got in there directly in the `$(document).ready(function(){`, like in all the examples: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not included jquery and ajax datatables js file, Please try by including the jquery and ajax data table jquery files.

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

Just javascript is not enough to run ajax datatables. Also you are using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

So you need to include jquery library as well. Please try by including the above two files and run your code.

Comment: thank you that solved the issue but now im getting an invalid json response error

Answer (score -1):

this works for me, with or without var dataTable..

```
    fetch_data();
    function fetch_data() {
        var dataTable = $('#my-example').DataTable({
           "processing" : true,
           "serverSide" : true,
           "order" : [],
           "ajax" : {
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
           }
        });
    }
```

have you included jquery & datatable and is there a table with id="my-example"?

**Note:** in your example you haven't closed the function with }

Comment: thank you this helped alot, i did not include it until recently so i just did